# Facebook Javascript API Requires IE to be in Protected Mode

Tags: facebook

I have a small webpage using the Facebook Javascript API.  Why does the API not work in Internet Explorer if Enable Protected Mode is turned off for the zone you are in?  getLoginStatus always returns unknown and FB.login displays a blank window if Protected Mode is off.  I have the channelURL set up although it does not seem to be using it as there are no references to it in my server logs.

My web page works fine in FF, Chrome, and in a Facebook tab but only works as a standalone page in IE if Enable Protected Mode is on.

I have been using IE9 but had somebody test IE10 with the same results.

Update: The reason I had Protected Mode off was because I had my site in the Intranet Zone and that was the default.  I have Protected Mode on now and things work good except I am getting Permission Denied errors.  After my page is running a few seconds, it comes up with Permission denied in xd_arbiter.php?version=26, line 33 character 50 if I am running IE9 in Compatibility mode or running IE9 in Browser Mode IE7 (from the F12 developer tools).  I just happen to be "lucky" that I was testing a site in the Intranet zone without Protected mode on plus running IE9 compatibility mode for that site (from a previous test).  Even though I received the permission denied errors, things still seem to work.  I assume now that I am not doing anything wrong, there are just issues in certain combinations that do not work.

Comment: Can you link to an example page?

Comment: http://user.govoutreach.com/fb/testfbreg.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this problem with IE9, IE10, IE11 with putting the facebook login button from the facebook javascript sdk on one of our sites.

It works in chrome & firefox but not in ie

I've identified the problem as our web page loading as in the "internet security" zone while facebook iframe / cookies load in the "internet security zone"

Our internet zone has "protected mode on" 
Our intranet zone has "protected mode off"

Because the two pages are loading in differnt zones, their cookie storage is stored in seperate directories and therefore they can't "link"

If both facebook and our local page are in the same zone
Or if both zones have the same "protected mode" setting then the api will work correctly

> [Protected Mode Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/02/09/528963.aspx)
>
> In Protected Mode IE writes/reads special Low versions of the cache,
>   TEMP folder, Cookies and History:
>
> Cache: %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary
>   Internet Files\Low Temp: %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Low Cookies:
>   %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low History:
>   %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History\Low